# Definition of variable in SQL Navigator

Tags: variables, sql-navigator

I have define variables in SQL Navigator 6.3;

**Scan Defines/Substituions is ON**;

**Sql/Scripts Options / Scan Binds/Substitutions is ON** too;

When I need use defined variables I had to run definition and selects together every time. Variables are dissapearing from subsitutions when I run some selects.

When I use the same SQL on others computer, I can run define one time and then selects automaticaly accept defined variables.

I don't now if it is essential information... on my PC is "define" in black color on others computer is red.

Vendy